# Changing '11AA22BB33' to 2 columns. One for number and other for digits

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, string-conversion

How can I change the string like `'11AA22BB33CC'` to something like below with Oracle SQL query

```
column1  |  column2
--------------------  
11       |  AA
22       |  BB  
33       |  CC
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think i got this working. Please correct me if there is any better solutions.

```
WITH temp AS(SELECT '11AA22BB33CC' c FROM dual)
SELECT regexp_substr(c,'[^[:digit:]]+',1,level),
       regexp_substr(c,'[0-9]+',1,level)
  FROM temp
connect by level < (regexp_count(c,'[0-9][A-Z]'))+1;
```